# Batch File If Statements causing close of CMD and not working

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am creating a should-be-simple batch file that will allow me to input a class name and it will take me to the correct google classroom. However, my if statement doesn't work, even when I input the word "Social Studies". It does not take me to my classroom, and on top of that, the CMD is just closed. When I remove the If Statement line, the code works fine and the cmd just stays open after inputting a class.

```
    set /p class="Enter Class: "

    IF "%class%" /I EQU "Social Studies" (START https://classroom.google.com) 
    
    cmd /k
```

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, type `if /?` and press then `[ENTER]` key, you'll learn how to use the command correctly. Also, as you're comparing strings, you should be using `==` as opposed to `EQU`. I'd also be interested to know why you're invoking a new, essentially empty, Command Prompt, at the end. Please also be very aware that `Set /P` requires some specific validation of input before using it, your end user cannot be trusted to input only what is expected, accidentally or otherwise.

Comment: I would be interested to know where you found that usage example for the `IF` command.

Comment: I solved this a while ago, I forgot how I did it. The cmd/k was just so that it didn't close after it was done.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF /I "%class%" EQU "Social Studies"...
```

The parsing logic for an `if` statement is very specific; `if [/i][NOT] arg1 op arg2` where `/i` and `not` are optional, but **must** if used, be used in that order.

Your code sees `/i` where it expects a comparison-operator and generates a syntax-error.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write @echo off whice prevents the prompt and contents of the batch file from being displayed.
I replaced the your EQ with == and now it works:

```
@echo off
set /p class="Enter Class: "

IF "%class%"=="Social Studies" (START https://classroom.google.com)
PAUSE
```

The `PAUSE` at the end will make the CMD remain open after it's done

Comment: Why did you remove the `/I` option?